# How to disable the "New" button on a related list in a VF page

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have a Visualforce page which displays a related list of child objects. The list, however, displays the "New" button, which I need to remove. Is this possible, or am I stuck with building a custom related-list-like table?

For example, this code

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:relatedList list="Contacts"/>
</apex:page>
```

will display the related list which will also display the "New Contact" button. My objects are custom, but the problem is equivalent. Can those buttons be affected either from Visualforce code or from an extension controller?

Let me add that I can't simply remove the New button from the layout, because I need the related list in different custom pages, sometimes with and sometimes without the New button.

Comment: I believe this has been answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/is-it-possible-to-remove-hide-the-new-button

Comment: Look at [this question and answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/remove-buttons-from-listview-in-visualforce-page/): `<apex:facet name="header">`.